# Is the Z value generated before the (r, s) values?

Tags: signature, ecdsa, sighash

I just want to confirm my understanding of signatures for P2PKH transactions.

The signature hash, `z`, is generated before generating the `r` and `s` values of a DER signature, correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If by `z` you mean the hash of the message, then yes, `z` is required to compute `s`. Therefore, strictly speaking, you need to compute it before `s`, but not necessarily before `r`.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm